# how can I replace a matrix element of NaN with 0 in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
a = matrix(c(5,10,NaN,NaN,4,5,3,NaN,NaN,2), nr=5)
a

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]   10    3
[3,]  NaN  NaN
[4,]  NaN  NaN
[5,]    4    2
```

Now I want to have those `NaN`'s replaced by zeros. I know `is.nan` function will return the indices of those elements, but how can I make use of the fact that if a `NaN` exists in a row, then all elements of that row are all `NaN`'s (as in the example above, rows 3 and 4). Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think there's any real need to make use of your knowledge about the rows, since replacing the `NaN`'s is so easy anyway:

```
a[is.nan(a)] = 0
```

Output:

```
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]   10    3
[3,]    0    0
[4,]    0    0
[5,]    4    2
```

Doing it using your approach:

```
> a = matrix(c(5,10,NaN,NaN,4,5,3,NaN,NaN,2), nr=5)
> nan_rows = is.nan(a[, 1])
> nan_rows
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> a[nan_rows, ] = 0
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]   10    3
[3,]    0    0
[4,]    0    0
[5,]    4    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me:

```
> a = matrix(c(5,10,NaN,NaN,4,5,3,NaN,NaN,2), nr=5)
> a[is.nan(a)] = 0
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]   10    3
[3,]    0    0
[4,]    0    0
[5,]    4    2
```